# Why the square of the difference of these two arrays is 3?

Tags: arrays, numpy

```
import numpy as np

vector = np.array([1])
vector2 = np.array([0])
(vector - vector2)^2
```

answer:

```
array([3])
```

Can someone explain what does `[3]` means?

Comment: It's because `^` != `**`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create arrays with `int` objects, the dtype will be an integer type. That means that bit twiddling is supported.

`^` is the bitwise XOR operator in python. `**` is exponentiation. Numpy implements both operations elwment-wise, as expected.

`1 ^ 2` -> 0001 XOR 0010 -> 0011 -> `3`

Comment: Thanks a lot Mad Physicist !

Comment: @Marty don't forget to select an answer by clicking on the check mark next to it. Also, see the formatting edits I made to your question.

Answer (score 0):

That isn't a square. `^` is the [xor (eXclusive OR) operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclusive_or). Squaring a variable would be done with the `**` operator (i.e., `(vector-vector2)**2`).

`vector - vector2` returns `array([1])`. When you xor it is a scalar, each element (or here - the single element) is xored individually, and 1 xor 2 is 3.